# Javascript dynamic array window with multiple answer options

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working on multiple arrays and occured to one problem.
When I have only one question div generated I can add additional questions without problem, but if I add another question div, I can't add additional questions to neither of both windows(same applies to any other number too), error which is I get is newdiv[counterq] is undefined. Can anybody help me with this issue? Thanks!

Also, how can I move div AddOption below created new one option input?

I'm new at programming sorry if won't explain in correct terms. Thanks!

Edit: Updated with new problem. Didn't wanted to create seperate topic.

HTML :

```js
var counterq = 0;
var limitq = 3;
var countero = 0;
var limito = 5;

function AddContent(divName) {
    countero = 0;
  if (counterq == limitq) {
    alert("You have reached the limit of adding " + counterq + " inputs");
  } else {
    var newdiv = new Array()
    newdiv[counterq] = document.createElement('div');
    newdiv[counterq].className = "ContentWindow[" + counterq + "]";   
    newdiv[counterq].innerHTML = "<p class='ContentQuestion'>Question " + (counterq + 1) + " </p> <input type='text' class='AddQuestionInput' value='Type your question' name='myQuestion[" + counterq + "]'>"; 
    if (countero == limito) {
      alert("You have reached the limit of adding " + countero + " options");
    } else {
        newdiv[counterq].innerHTML += "<div class='OptionInputOuterWindow'><span class='OptionInputDescription'>Option " + (countero + 1) + "</span> <input type='text' class='AddOptionInput' name='myQuestion[" + counterq + "]"+"[myInputs]"+"[" + countero + "]'></div>";
        newdiv[counterq].innerHTML += "<div class='OptionInputOuterWindow'><span class='OptionInputDescription'>Option " + (countero + 2) + "</span> <input type='text' class='AddOptionInput' name='myQuestion[" + counterq + "]"+"[myInputs]"+"[" + (countero+1) + "]'></div>";
        document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv[counterq]);
        countero += 2;
         AddOption = function() {
            var counterq = 0;
            var limito = 5;
            if (countero == limito) {
                alert("You have reached the limit of adding " + countero + " options");
            } else {
                newdiv[counterq].innerHTML += "<div class='OptionInputOuterWindow'><span class='OptionInputDescription'>Option " + (countero + 1) + "</span> <input type='text' class='AddOptionInput' name='myQuestion[" + counterq + "]"+"[myInputs]"+"[" + countero + "]'></div>";
                $("div[class*=ContentWindow]").css("height", "+=27");
                countero++;
            }
        };
    }
        $(".container").css("height", "+=344");
        newdiv[counterq].innerHTML += "<div class='AddOption' onclick='AddOption();'><img src='/img/Plussmall.png'>Add option</div>";
    counterq++;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <div id="Content"></div>


        <div class="AddContent" onclick="AddContent('Content');" >
         <img src="/img/Plussmall.png">Add content
        </div>
```

Comment: `countero + 1` doesn't do anything -- it calculates the addition, but doesn't put it anywhere. If you want to increase `countero` by 2, use `countero += 2;` instead of `countero++`

Answer (score 1):

If you want the counter to increase by 2, use `countero += 2` instead of `countero++`.

```js
var counterq = 0;
var limitq = 3;
var countero = 0;
var limito = 5;

function AddContent(divName) {
  if (counterq == limitq) {
    alert("You have reached the limit of adding " + counterq + " inputs");
  } else {
    var newdiv = new Array()
    newdiv[counterq] = document.createElement('div');
    newdiv[counterq].className = 'new-rect';
    if (counterq == limito) {
      alert("You have reached the limit of adding " + countero + " options");
    } else {
      newdiv[counterq].innerHTML = "Entry " + (countero + 1) + " <br><input type='text' name='myInputs[" + countero + "]'><br>Entry " + (countero + 2) + " <br><input type='text' name='myInputs[" + countero + "]'><br>";
      document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv[counterq]);
      countero += 2;
    }

    counterq++;
  }
}
```

```css
.new-rect {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="Content"></div>

<input type="button" class="AddContent" value="Add content" onclick="AddContent('Content');">
```

Comment: Thanks! That really helps. However I'm still having issue figuring out how to reset 'countero' for each window

Comment: Where are you creating different windows?

Comment: There's no `window.open()` call in your code to create multiple windows. Everything is in the same browser window.

Comment: You're just creating multiple DIVs, not multiple windows.

Comment: Oh, my mistake. I meant not seperate url window but just just drawn window in same page.

Comment: Yes, multiple DIVs, my bad. I'm new at programming.

Comment: Then just set `countero` to `0` at the beginning of `AddContent`.

Comment: Thanks, also another issue is how could i add second input countero+1?

Comment: I'm not really understanding you. Could you update the question, and show what you want the resulting HTML to be like?

Comment: I asked you to update the question, not post it in a comment.